# Multi-delimited string to list of objects using linq and lambdas

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

### Overview

I have a string delimited by commas, representing objects, and spaces, representing properties of those objects:

```
string sOrderBy = "Column1 ASC, Column2 DESC";
```

I need to convert it to a `List<OrderByColumn>` where `OrderByColumn` is:

```
public class OrderByColumn
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAscending { get; set; }
}
```

### Problem

```
sOrderBy.Split(',').Select(x => new OrderByColumn()
{
    ColumnName = x.Trim().Split(' ')[0].Trim(),
    IsAscending = x.Trim().Split(' ')[1].Trim() == "ASC" ? true : false
}).ToList<OrderByColumn>();
```

The above code works, but there's some redundancy in calling `x.Trim().Split(' ')` more than once. (Also, I'm aware the code currently assumes that the 0 & 1 array values are there).

Is there a way to remove this redundancy? Somehow pass the result of `x.Trim().Split(' ')` to an anonymous function and then return an `OrderByColumn` object from there?

I know I could solve this issue using two for/foreach loops, but linq and lambdas are so cool! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about introducing a temporary variable inside the `Select`:

```
sOrderBy.Split(',').Select(x => 
    {
        var trimmedSplitted = x.Trim().Split(' ');
        return new OrderByColumn()
        {
            ColumnName = trimmedSplitted[0].Trim(),
            IsAscending = (trimmedSplitted[1].Trim() == "ASC")
        };
    }
).ToList<OrderByColumn>()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sOrderBy.Split(',')
        .Select(csv=> csv.Trim().Split(' '))
        .Select(splitBySpaces => new OrderByColumn()
                     {
                         ColumnName = splitBySpaces[0].Trim(),
                         IsAscending = (splitBySpaces[1].Trim() == "ASC")
                     })
        .ToList<OrderByColumn>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add an extract select:

```
sOrderBy.Split(',').
    Select(x => x.Trim().Split(' ')).
    Select(x => new OrderByColumn(){
        ColumnName = x[0].Trim(), 
        IsAscending = x[1].Trim() == "ASC"}).
    ToList()
```

I hope this work out for you.